# Brackets needed when using infix approach?

Tags: scala, infix-notation

Really simple Scala question.

How come the infix approach to 1 + 2 does not need brackets?

```
scala>1 + 2
res7: Int = 3
```

But the dot approach does?

```
scala>1 .+(2)
res8: Int = 3

scala> 1 .+2
<console>:1: error: ';' expected but integer literal found.
   1 .+2
       ^
```

Comment: When you call method by dot, you need to enclose parameters in brackets, just like in regular `obj.somemethod(someparam,foo,bar)`

Comment: Does not need brackets: `1.+ 2`, but result type is `Double`

Comment: @idonnie Yes, but this is something else. What you have written is equivalent to `1.0 + 2` (the dot means decimal separator, not method invocation)

Comment: @idonnie 1.+2 converts the 1 to double and answer will be 3.0.

Comment: @ghik thanks but there must be a space between the 1 and the .  So when you say the when a method is called on a object the parameter must be in brackets do you mean 1 is the object?

Comment: @dublintech Yes, everything in Scala is an object so `1 .+(2)` means to call method `+` on object `1` with parameter `2`. Infix notation (`1 + 2`) actually means the same thing (it is syntactic sugar to call method with one parameter). And about the space before dot - look at my previous comment. The space is needed so that dot is interpreted as method invocation and not as decimal separator.

Comment: @ghik Thanks. I'll accept that as answer if you want to put it forward as answer.

Comment: @dublintech Here it is :)

Comment: Note that instead of the space before the dot, you may also use brackets, like `(1).+(2)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything in Scala is an object so `1 .+(2)` means to call method `+` on object `1` with parameter `2`. And of course if you call a method like this, you need to enclose parameters in brackets, just like in regular `obj.somemethod(someparam,foo,bar)`.

Infix notation (`1 + 2`) actually means the same thing (it is syntactic sugar to call method with one parameter).

And the space before dot is needed so that dot is interpreted as method invocation and not as decimal separator. Otherwise `1.+(2)` or `1.+2` will be interpreted as `1.0 + 2`.

Comment: I don't like the idea of promulgating a myth. Not everything in Scala is an object in the sense of being an instance of a class. The language only makes it appear that way, performing transparent boxing and unboxing or supplying built-in operations for JVM native types.

Comment: Citing from http://www.scala-lang.org/node/128: _In contrast to Java, all values in Scala are objects (including numerical values and functions). Since Scala is class-based, all values are instances of a class._ Of course, this does not mean that everything in Scala is represented in JVM as an object. But nevertheless, in Scala terms, every value is an object which means it is an instance of a class (again, in Scala terms) that has methods, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's to do with language definition:

> A left-associative binary operation e1 op e2 is interpreted as e1.op(e2).

http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf

The form 1 .+ 2 is not specified anywhere so my guess is that the compiler is looking for either 1 + 2 or 1.+(2). In fact the compiler converts 1+2 into 1.+(2) normally. When using the . it expects a function and not the infix syntax.

Bottom line: you can use either but not something half way there.

PD: someone commented that calling a method you need to use it like this: `obj.somemethod(someparam,foo,bar)` but on that case you can also do this: `obj somemethod (someparam,foo,bar)` and you have to leave the spaces for it to work.